# Can "rat de bibliothèque" be an attributive adjective, as in "du genre rat de bibliothèque"?

Tags: grammaire

I said in conversation:

> Je ne suis pas **du genre rat de bibliothèque**, moi. Je ne l'ai jamais été.

It was a spur-of-the-moment thing, I'm afraid, as I usually use the structure "du genre à + infinitive" or "du genre + adjective" but not "du genre + noun" like "du genre rat de bibliothèque". Unless... the nominal phrase "rat de bibliothèque" can also serve as an attributive adjective? Or should I have phrased it otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

*Du [genre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/genre)* can be followed by a substantive. Your sentence is perfectly idiomatic.

See for example http://jaimelafrance.tourisme.fr/dossier/hauts-lieux-de-lecture/ :

> Si vous êtes du genre rat de bibliothèque, on vous propose d’en sortir, de votre bibliothèque, et de vous aérer un peu pour aller grignoter quelques pages dans des lieux très particuliers.

*Être du genre* usage is quite flexible as it can be followed by anything that describes the expected *genre*, whether an adjective, a substantive, a pronoun, an interjection, a relative clause, a full sentence... although guillemets are often used when the sentence would have looked too ungrammatical otherwise.

*Du genre* can be understood as a shortcut for *du genre/de la catégorie que l'on peut définir avec/par/comme/...*

When an adjective is used, it is expected to agree with *genre* (masculine) but the rule is often relaxed to allow agreement with the subject :

> *Ma fille est du genre jaloux.*
>
> *Ma fille est du genre jalouse.*

Back to your example, *rat de bibliothèque* can be used as an attributive adjective in a sentence like:

> *Ma voisine est très « rat de bibliothèque ».*

See also http://www.academie-francaise.fr/genre for even more relaxed uses of *genre*.

Comment: Can you think of other examples of  "genre" being followed by a substantive?

Comment: Oui, jlliagre a raison de dire que c'est idiomatique. Cela reste néanmoins, à mon opinion, une construction fautive. Genre + substantif est parfaitement correcte SANS l'article **du** précédent. (un petit salon, genre boudoir) C'est, à mon sens grammaticalement incorrect lorsque précédé de l'article qui fait de, *du genre" une locution adverbiale et qui, comme le soupçonne Con-gras-tue-les-chiens ne pourra par conséquent s'entendre que suivie d'un adjectif ou d'un verbe.

Comment: Pour continuer ma démonstration plus haut que je ne peux plus éditér... Remplace "*du genre*" par "*plutôt*" et tu verras que cela ne marche pas.

Comment: @aCOSwt Hi. Tu veux dire que c'est une locution fautive pourtant très répandue ? À tel point qu'elle passe aujourd'hui pour une construction acceptable, ou bien presque ?

Answer (score 2):

Sous l'angle grammatical donc :

on part de : *xyzt est du genre tuv*

Si on prend *genre* pour un substantif alors *tuv* est nécessairement un adjectif.
épithète, il se fléchira alors impérativement au masculin singulier.

On observe cependant que l'accord de l'adjectif se fait le plus souvent avec le sujet xyzt.

*Les chambres sont du genre luxueu**ses*** (Guide du routard)

"genre" ne peut donc plus être tenu pour un nom, un tel accord fait de "*du genre*" une locution adverbiale qui, comme le souligne justement Con-gras-tue-les-chiens ne peut être suivie que d'un adjectif ou d'un verbe.

D'un autre coté, on a *genre*, substantif qui, placé en apposition ou en incise, c'est bien à dire SANS l'article *du*, peut fort bien être suivi d'un substantif :

*Un petit salon, genre boudoir* (Triolet, Prem. accroc,1945, p. 143).

On observe très exactement (et c'est logique) les mêmes constructions qu'avec "style" :

*Une église **de style** gothique* (gothique adjectif)

*Une église, **style** gothique* (gothique nom)

On observera que dans un grand nombre de cas (comme pour mon exemple ci-dessus) l'adjectif est substantivé identiquement. anglais / un anglais, comique / un comique, baroque / un baroque.
Je présume que cette invariance orthographique a entraîné la confusion fautive entre les deux formes et que certains utilisent aujourd'hui l'une ou l'autre forme sans se soucier de fonction grammaticale.

Mais, pour ma part, je déplorerai que l'ambiance, **genre canicule**, me fasse arrêter ici ma démonstration...

Tout en observant que l'ambiance, **du genre caniculaire**, me... pousse vers la même fin. ;)

En conclusion donc, Oui! Con-gras-tue-les-chiens, tu as raison : *rat de bibliothèque* est une locution nominale et donc *un type du genre rat de bibliothèque*... ça pique un peu les yeux!

Bon... ne t'en veux pas trop, on dira que sur ce coup, tu l'as adjectivée et on n'en parlera plus.

Comment: En vous demandant pardon de créer un article pour cela mais il est malcommode d'éditer les commentaires dans lesquels je réalise n'avoir pas été assez clair.
Sans compter que le système râle après un certain nombre...

Comment: Dans la mesure où ca répond à la question il n'y a aucun souci...